# Plotly Subplots with Multiple Traces

Tags: python, plotly, subplot, plotly-python

Making a plotly subplot with multiple traces on the same plot.

So I'm making subplots that I plan to put on an HTML file for web viewing. However, the issue is that each plot of mine has multiple traces and is made in px.line. All right, so I tried to make a plot with multiple traces using go.Scatter, but that isn't working either.

Here is the current code:

```
import pandas as pd 
import plotly.express as px 
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly
from itertools import cycle
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots 


#below code imports file needed at the moment
F62Ext1 = pd.read_csv("F6-2_Ext1.csv")
F62Ext2 = pd.read_csv("F6-2_Ext2.csv")


#using a savgol filter to smooth out data in python
from scipy.signal import savgol_filter
#definition of savgol filter for dataframe written below
def savgol(x):
    return savgol_filter(x,101,6)
F62Ext1_smoothed = F62Ext1.apply(savgol)
F62Ext2_smoothed = F62Ext2.apply(savgol)

F62E1_CH1 = go.Scatter(x = F62Ext1_smoothed['Time'], y = [F62Ext1_smoothed['CH1'],F62Ext1['ActivePoke'], F62Ext1['CueLight']], name = "F62Ext1, Channel 1")
F62E2_CH1 = go.Scatter(x = F62Ext2_smoothed['Time'], y = [F62Ext2_smoothed['CH1'],F62Ext2['ActivePoke'], F62Ext2['CueLight']], name = "F62Ext2, Channel 1")

fig = make_subplots(rows = 1, cols = 2, shared_yaxes = True)
fig.add_trace(F62E1_CH1, row = 1, col = 1)
fig.add_trace(F62E2_CH1, row = 1, col = 2)
```

Which produces the following:
[go.Scatter plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VNu0.png)

However, what I am trying to obtain is this:
[px.line plot with multiple traces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTi3k.png)

How do I correct this error?

edit: the dict for F62E1 is below:

```
{'Time': {0: 0.0, 1: 0.1, 2: 0.2, 3: 0.3, 4: 0.4},
 'CH1': {0: -0.169504148,
  1: -0.372732867,
  2: -0.323666804,
  3: -0.352484157,
  4: -0.327975913},
 'CH2': {0: -0.188884746,
  1: -0.301823346,
  2: -0.13172756,
  3: -0.456077945,
  4: -0.543653381},
 'CH3': {0: 0.03599356,
  1: -0.029965731,
  2: 0.014807156,
  3: -0.06392204,
  4: -0.041387216},
 'CH4': {0: -0.082626583,
  1: -0.071240774,
  2: -0.055854863,
  3: -0.137854075,
  4: -0.134953954},
 'CH5': {0: -0.104248439,
  1: -0.241010992,
  2: -0.249843885,
  3: -0.306350559,
  4: -0.223923059},
 'CH6': {0: -0.020229121,
  1: -0.359940514,
  2: -0.229173544,
  3: -0.266795437,
  4: -0.278069671},
 'CH7': {0: -0.209219168,
  1: -0.255944829,
  2: -0.215244963,
  3: -0.290505347,
  4: -0.28456927},
 'CH8': {0: 0.093962928,
  1: 1.2574526,
  2: 1.75068895,
  3: 1.356159013,
  4: 0.676462295},
 'CH9': {0: -0.150238434,
  1: -0.167165814,
  2: -0.057212299,
  3: -0.20998062,
  4: -0.351662263},
 'CH10': {0: -0.306078824,
  1: -0.399363635,
  2: -0.281349569,
  3: -0.53463429,
  4: -0.383537615},
 'CH11': {0: -0.189443456,
  1: -0.161361134,
  2: -0.223323043,
  3: -0.338406151,
  4: -0.339504188},
 'CH12': {0: -0.174074045,
  1: -0.230008948,
  2: -0.255067313,
  3: -0.380150306,
  4: -0.393756259},
 'CH13': {0: -0.123562058,
  1: -0.271150428,
  2: -0.251144972,
  3: -0.379664224,
  4: -0.393714865},
 'CH14': {0: -0.233391565,
  1: -0.276967731,
  2: -0.236738984,
  3: -0.44725073,
  4: -0.455074619},
 'CH15': {0: -0.234460706,
  1: -0.368129274,
  2: -0.264646375,
  3: -0.438000119,
  4: -0.40056134},
 'CH16': {0: -0.267852578,
  1: -0.224666613,
  2: -0.189448701,
  3: -0.291014541,
  4: -0.387302535},
 'ActivePoke': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0},
 'CueLight': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0},
 'Pump': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0},
 'InactivePoke': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0}}
```

Comment: can you include a sample of `F62Ext1` or `F62Ext2` so we can more easily reproduce your error? you can copy and paste the output from `F62Ext1.head().to_dict()` into your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that plotly can't understand this trace:

```
F62E1_CH1 = go.Scatter(x = F62Ext1_smoothed['Time'], y = [F62Ext1_smoothed['CH1'],F62Ext1['ActivePoke'], F62Ext1['CueLight']], name = "F62Ext1, Channel 1")
```

You can instead store the `go.Scatter` objects in a list, and then loop through them to add the traces individually. I have also made use of the parameters `legendgroup` and `showlegend` so that all traces for a subplot can be selected or deselected together – this can removed if it's not necessary.

For example:

```
F62E1_CH1_traces = [
    go.Scatter(
        x = F62Ext1_smoothed['Time'], 
        y = y, 
        name = "F62Ext1, Channel 1",
        legendgroup = "F62Ext1, Channel 1",
        showlegend = showlegend
    ) for y, showlegend in zip(
        [F62Ext1_smoothed['CH1'],F62Ext1['ActivePoke'], F62Ext1['CueLight']],
        [True, False, False]
    ) 
]
F62E1_CH2_traces = [
    go.Scatter(
        x = F62Ext2_smoothed['Time'], 
        y = y, 
        name = "F62Ext2, Channel 2",
        legendgroup = "F62Ext2, Channel 2",
        showlegend = showlegend
    ) for y, showlegend in zip(
        [F62Ext2_smoothed['CH1'],F62Ext2['ActivePoke'], F62Ext2['CueLight']],
        [True, False, False]
    )
]

fig = make_subplots(rows = 1, cols = 2, shared_yaxes = True)
for F62E1_CH1_trace in F62E1_CH1_traces:
    fig.add_trace(F62E1_CH1_trace, row = 1, col = 1)
for F62E1_CH2_trace in F62E1_CH2_traces:
    fig.add_trace(F62E1_CH2_trace, row = 1, col = 2)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! That worked well for me - the legend is something I'm probably going to have to edit a little to show all components, but this was able to combine my graphs perfectly!